# Calling Windows managed .dll from Cordova App. WinRT Component?

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, dll, windows-10

I need to expose a managed .dll to a Cordova App.  My thought process here is to create a plugin which itself will communicate with the managed .dll.

This is STRICTLY for Windows10.  I don't need to support anything other than Windows10.

Is there a better way to make calls to a managed .dll from a Cordova App than what I outline below?  Is a Windows Runtime Component the best way to go about doing this?

As far as I understand, the best route to do this is to create a Windows Runtime Component.

i.e. JavaScript -> calls www\myplugin.js (interface) -> calls windows\myproxyplugin.js -> calls the WinRT component -> calls the managed .dll?

Am I on the right path to doing this?  If not can you please offer the best recommended approach for being able to make calls into a managed .dll from a Cordova App

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a correct way - see this issue for sample solution: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11825. Note that WP8.1/10 requires that a dll Package Action to be changed from `Content` to `None` to avoid deploy errors.

Comment: @daserge that was very helpful.  Thanks for the link. Ultimately what I need/needed is just a simple complete example.  I think what you posted above gets me close to that